# How to replace carriage return

Tags: php

I have a variable (`$myClass[0]->comment;`) that has carriage return in it. I want to replace all the carriage return in that variable with "`\n`"
how can I do that.
below may help a bit

```
$myClass[0]->comment;
```

Here is some output

```
<?php  
          $test = explode(chr(13),$myClass[0]->comment );  
          var_dump($test);  

?>
```

OUTPUT

```
array  
  0 => string '12' (length=2)  
  1 => string '  
' (length=1)   
  2 => string '  
22' (length=3)
```

All I want is `\n` instead of carriage return.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to replace each CR (\r) with LF (\n), do this

```
$str=str_replace("\r", "\n", $str);
```

If you want a literal \n, do this

```
$str=str_replace("\r", "\\n", $str);
```

It's more likely you want to replace CR LF, in which simply search for `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work for the life of me. Ended going to hex and back.  $str=hex2bin(str_replace("5c72","",bin2hex($str)));

Comment: 5C = \ 72 = r so all you've done is a really inefficient replacement of the literal sequence `\r` - i.e. your string didn't have a CR in it - it was already escaped.

Answer (score 10):

```
preg_replace('/\r\n?/', "\n", $str);
```

This converts both Windows and Mac line endings to Unix line endings.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str_replace()` to do this:

```
$test = str_replace("\r", "\n", $myClass[0]->comment);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use str_replace

http://us.php.net/str_replace

```
str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);
```

if you first wan't to clear out compound \r\n, so you don't get \n\n you could do

```
str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);
str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

No you don't. You want this:

```
str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $myClass[0]->comment)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something a bit more functional (easy to use anywhere):

```
function replace_carriage_return($replace, $string)
{
    return str_replace(array("\n\r", "\n", "\r"), $replace, $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
str_replace( "\r", "\n", $string );
```