# PHP new line for an encrypting app

Tags: php

I am working on an encrypting app. I read a file and i change every character with other character. When i decrypt the encrypted file, the result is displayed on a single line, not on multiple lines like in the original file.
I try to use case "\r\n" to detect a new line but it isn't working.
Is there any better way to detect a new line and echo 'm'? And on the decrypt i will read 'm' i will know to make a new line.
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$file=fopen("Demonstration.txt","r");

while(!feof($file))
{
    switch(fgetc($file))
    { 
        case "\r\n":
        echo 'm';
        break;
    }
}
fclose($file);
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All I can say is read this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: Obfuscating content is not the same as encryption.

Comment: i have read the information on that link. i was wrong when i chose the word encryption. sorry.

Comment: You have to check for all ways that a new line can be made, you are only checking for one. You can see this question for some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135919/how-to-replace-carriage-return

Answer (score 0):

fgetc returns a single character. "\r\n"'s length is two chars.

So, you can replace \n with "m" and ignore \r :

```
switch(fgetc($file))
{ 
    case "\n":
    echo 'm';
    break;
}
```